# Bootstrap slider with simple form

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, haml

I have a code for bootstrap slider http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-slider/ below, but for some reason it just shows single handle, not a range. Can someone suggest what the problem is here please?

```
     = form.text_field :price, id: 'slider', type: 'text', data: 
{'slider-id' => 'slider', 'slider-min' => '0', 'slider-max' => '4020', 
'slider-step' => '1', 'slider-value' => '14' }
```

price is a string

jquery

```
$("#slider").slider();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this worked for me instead

```
$("#slider").slider({
            min: 5,
            max: 4500,
            step: 5,
            value: [5,4500],
            tooltip: "hide"
        });
```